# How to implement Google Reader like UI?

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to implement a UI on my Android app that feels like the Google Reader for Android. The user can swipe left/right to move to the next/previous view. Is it a build in widget, or do I need to implement myself?

P.S. I want to implement this effect on Android 2.3.3, mobile phone, not 3 or above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at:
[Horizontal View Swiping with ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20blogspot/hsDu%20%28Android%20Developers%20Blog%29)